# How to use pylint with optional objects

Tags: python, pylint

I have a class:

```
class MyClass:
    LOOKUP: Optional[Dict] = None  # it is supposed to be a
                   # dictionary, but each derived class
                   # will prepare own version. It has to be done later.
                   # None value indicates that initialization is not done yet.
    @classmethod
    def do_smthn(cls):
        if cls.LOOKUP is None:
            # the LOOKUP is not initialized for this class yet, so
            cls.LOOKUP = cls.prepare_lookup()
        # now this class has own cls.LOOKUP dictionary, I can use it
        assert cls.LOOKUP is not None
        return cls.LOOKUP[42]
```

pylint complains: E1136: Value 'cls.LOOKUP' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)

Well, I understand why pylint is not happy. I can disable pylint warning on each line where I use LOOKUP - but that's not convenient.

I tried to annotate the LOOKUP with 'dict' type (the above code already contains the annotation) - it doesn't help. pylint still reports same problem. But I still want to tell pylint somehow that LOOKUP is a dictionary.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: "*[...] it doesn't help.*": Could you show us the new code too? How does it *not* help?

Comment: @InSync I have updated the question: now sample code includes my attempt to use annotations

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional` from the `typing` module exactly for this.

```
from typing import Optional, Dict
    
class MyClass:
    LOOKUP : Optional[Dict] = None
    ...
```

Then whenever you use LOOKUP you have to do an assertion or an if statement.

```
assert cls.LOOKUP is not None
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I tried to do. But pylint still reports the same problem.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the exact warning pylint gives you and add it to the question.

Comment: I run pylint manually from command line. `pylint km.py`. And this is the exact text it produces: "km.py:17:15: E1136: Value 'cls.LOOKUP' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)"